# Self Study question on Conditional Probability

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

I am currently doing a self-study on Conditional Probability. I was faced with a question where I was provided with $P(a)$, $P(b)$, $P(c)$, $P(a \mid d)$, $P(b \mid d)$ and $P(c \mid d)$.

The full context of the question:

> A departmental store reports that 30% of payment is collected in cash, 60% in credit card and 10% in debit card. 20% of cash purchases, 90% of credit card purchases and 80% of debit card purchases are for more than 200 dollars in purchases. What the probability that Sue paid cash if she purchased a new bag that costs $98.

Thus, I took $a = \mbox{payment in cash}$, $b = \mbox{payment in credit}$ and $c = \mbox{payment as debit}$. $P$ represented the probability that payments went above 200 dollars.

I was attempting to find out what is $P(d)$.

My attempt (which did not seem to yield the right answer):
$$
P(a)P(a \mid d) + P(b) P(b \mid d) + P(c)P(c \mid d)
$$

Appreciate some guidance please.

**Edit**

Based on the latest guidance, I still failed to answer the question with the final answer being 1.43567, however still deferring from the original answer of 0.750. My answer seemed grossly wrong.

My solution:

> Let $a = \mbox{cash}$, $b =  \mbox{credit}$, $c =  \mbox{debit}$ and $d =  \mbox{payment amounts more than 200 dollars}$.
>
> Therefore $P(a) = 0.3$, $P(b) = 0.6$, $P(c) = 0.1$, $P(d \mid a) = 0.2$, $P(d \mid b) = 0.9$ and $P(d \mid c) = 0.8$.
>
> I will first attempt to find
>   \begin{align*}
> P(d)
>  &= P(a)P(d \mid a) + P(b)P(d \mid b) +  P(c)P(d \mid c) \\
>  &= 0.3 \cdot 0.2 + 0.6 \cdot 0.9 + 0.1 \cdot 0.8 = 0.68.
> \end{align*}
>
> Then, I will attempt to find the value of $P(a \mid d)$ using the bayes theorem which results in $(0.2+0.3)/0.68 = 0.73529$.
>
> Next, to find $P(a \mid d^c)$, we use the formula
>   $P(d) = P(a)P(a \mid d) + P(d^c) P(a \mid d^c)$.
>   $0.68 = 0.3 \cdot 0.73529 + 0.32 P(a \mid d^c) = 1.43567$.

Since the probability can never be more than $1$, my answer looks terrible wrong. Appreciate and guidance please.

Comment: Start by drawing a diagram (have you included all relevant information in your question)? Why would you expect your attempt to yield P(D)? What facts did you use in constructing that answer?

Comment: Hi Glen. Thanks for responding. I'd edit the question abobe to add the context.

Comment: On a separate note Glen, I was wondering if I were even on the right track. I understand that to find P(T), I can do the following: P(S)xP(T|S) + P(U)xP(T|U) + P(V)xP(T|V). But over here, it seems that I might have wrongly place the condition?

Comment: Do you notice the essential difference between what you have in your comment and what you have in your question?

Comment: Are you really sure about the computation of $P(a \mid d)$?

Comment: You define A, B, C and P. What's D?

Comment: @Glen_b D is the probability that payment amounts to more than 200 dollars.

Comment: Why do you have both A, B, C etc and also a, b, c etc?

Comment: Woops. They actually mean the same thing, just that one I used upper case, while in another, I used lower case. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Can you fix you question please? You need to fix the D/P duplication (two things representing the same event) as well as the upper/lower case issue

Comment: This question still needs to be fixed. Was the discussion of Bayes theorem of any use?

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for the speedy reverts. had not be able to get access to internet over the past day. I have managed to incorporate your advice and found the answer. thank you so much. I will continue to practice similar questions to further iron in the concept

Comment: @Glen_b Ive fixed the question

Comment: An improvement thanks. You still have "*P represented the probability that payments went above 200 dollars. [...] I was attempting to find out what is P(d).*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this question, but I believe the intent is to use [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B | A)\, P(A)}{P(B)}$$

specifically the version where the denominator is split up:

$$P(A_i|B) = \frac{P(B|A_i)\,P(A_i)}{\sum\limits_j P(B|A_j)\,P(A_j)}\cdot$$

Bayes' theorem is just the thing for swapping the direction of conditioning around (A|B in terms of B|A).

Aside from the fact that you're dealing with $D^c$ when you information is in terms of $D$, it's a very straightforward application of the theorem. You need to add an extra little step of thought to sort that out in the expression on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the advice and inputs everyone. Following's my working:

[image]